# c# weird Dictionary ContainsKey or StringComaprer

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, containskey, stringcomparer

It's some kind of weird magic, ContainsKey returns false. I tried to use InvariantCulture comparer with the same result.

```
GameCommands = new Dictionary<string, GameCommand>(StringComparer.Ordinal)
            {
                {"Start new game with deck", StartGame},
                {"​Tell color", TellColor},
                {"​Tell rank", TellRank},
                {"​Drop card", Drop},
                {"​Play card", Play},
            };
Debug.WriteLine(GameCommands.ContainsKey("Tell color"));
```

**False**

I solve it by removing quotes in keys and typing them again. I want to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have zero-width spaces (U+200B) at the start of some of your strings. For example, copy this:

```
{"​Drop card", Drop},
```

into the [Unicode Explorer here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx#explorer), and you'll see something like this:

[image: Unicode explorer]

Now, we don't know where that character came from, but I suspect you were copying and pasting the text from somewhere else.

Note that there's nothing wrong with the behaviour of the dictionary, or of `string` or anything in .NET here... it's *just* a problem in your source code. You'd see exactly the same behaviour if you expressed the same string more clearly:

```
{"\u200BDrop card", Drop},
```

Comment: `{"\u2008Drop card", Drop},` ----> `{"\u200BDrop card", Drop},` looking at your table

Comment: @FelixCastor: Doh! Thanks, fixed.